# How many integration tests, and how many per Jest testing file?

Tags: testing, jestjs, integration-testing, nestjs

I'm currently running Jest with NestJS and I'm writing some integration tests.

I'm encountering a few timing problems in Jest, and am wondering if it's to do with the number of tests in my file. I have 9 *describe* blocks, and 32 *test* and *it* blocks in my largest file - is this too many?

As a more general question, how many integration tests should I write? All of these tests are to do with the login/register functionality of my app - is this too many? Can I ever have *too many* tests?

Please could someone also point out how/where can I find out about conventions for Jest and integration testing as a whole?

Comment: Quantity != quality. There are no conventions, and this isn't specific to Jest in any way. Generally, unit tests should be more preferred over integration tests, search for "test pyramid". You can have too many tests in the sense that they need maintenance while having not much value, and there could be better investments for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have 9 describe blocks, and 32 test and it blocks in my largest file - is this too many?

I don't know Jest, but I'm going to go with "no". 9 blocks and 32 tests is very small.

> As a more general question, how many integration tests should I write?

As many as you need to cover your functionality, edge cases, and [prevent bugs from reoccurring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing).

> All of these tests are to do with the login/register functionality of
> my app - is this too many?

Depends on how complex your login/registration process is, and how many different ways it could go wrong. However, keep in mind that most of it should be done as unit tests. For example, a test for what happens when the registration email fails to send would be a unit test. Whereas confirming that the user is redirected after registering would be an integration test.

> Can I ever have too many tests?

No. But you can have poorly written tests.

These answers might seem glib, but just as [Lines Of Code (LOC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) is a poor metric, number of tests is also a poor metric. It's an inflexible number that does not take into account what you are testing.

Because they are responsible for testing the code, your tests reflect the complexity of the code and will often be as large or larger than your code base.

> Please could someone also point out how/where can I find out about conventions for Jest and integration testing as a whole?

While this is not specific to Jest, ["A Node.js Guide to Actually Doing Integration Tests"](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/nodejs-guide-integration-tests) provides a good overview. The Jest documentation has an example of [testing a React app](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react) and lists [tutorials for other frameworks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/testing-frameworks).